# If Clause in SQL Loader

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, sql-loader

It is possible to use IF CLAUSE in sql loader? I had written a code but it is giving me error.

```
INTO TABLE TF_RTB9_DTL 
WHEN ((01) = 'D') OR (if 
(POA_COU_VAL = 0) 
then MAST_POA_ID = null 
end if) 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY "~" OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' 
TRAILING NULLCOLS 
( 

TRANS_TYP POSITION(3), 
BO_ID , 
NAME , 
MID_NAM , 
LAS_NAM , 
PAN , 
NAM_FIR_JOINT , 
MIDD_NAM_FIR_JOINT, 
LAS_NAM_FIR_JOINT , 
PAN_FIR_JOINT , 
NAM_SEC_JOINT , 
MIDD_NAM_SEC_JOINT, 
LAS_NAM_SEC_JOINT , 
PAN_SEC_JOINT , 
ADD_LIN_1 , 
ADD_LIN_2 , 
ADD_LIN_3, 
CITY , 
STATE , 
COUNTRY , 
PIN_COD , 
PERM_ADD_LIN_1 , 
PERM_ADD_LIN_2 , 
PERM_ADD_LIN_3 , 
PERM_CITY , 
PERM_STATE , 
PERM_COUNTRY , 
PERM_PIN_COD , 
POA_COU_VAL , 
MAST_POA_ID , 
TRANS_ID 
)
```

If POA_COU_VAL is 0 than POA_COU_VAL must be null and next value should be enter in  TRANS_ID. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4):

SQL*Loader is a program for loading large batches of data.  It has only limited facilities for manipulating the data during the load process.

If you want to transform the data you should be using external tables instead.  These are very similar to SQL*Loader (the definition uses virtually the same syntax but they present the data file to the database as a table. That means you can use SQL on it.  So instead on invoking SQL*Loader from the command line you woudl run an insert statement like this:

```
insert into target_table
select * from external table;
```

Only in your situation you need to explode the project of the SELECT clause so you can include a CASE() statement to implement your additional logic.

[Find out more about external tables here.](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/et_concepts.htm#i1009391)

Comment: hey can i use a case or decode statement. For example:- 

decode(POA_COU_VAL, 0, MAST_POA_ID)

Comment: CASE is a more flexible function than DECODE, but use DECODE if you want.

Answer (score 2):

SQL*Loader `WHEN` clause has only limited boolean operators, especially `OR` is missing ( see http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/ldr_control_file.htm#i1005657).

If you *have* to use SQL*Loader (and can't switch to external tables as APC suggested), you need to multiply the `INTO` sections for each part of your `OR` clause.

For example:

```
INTO TABLE TF_RTB9_DTL 
WHEN (01) = 'D'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY "~" OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' 
TRAILING NULLCOLS 
( 
TRANS_TYP POSITION(3),
...      
...      
MAST_POA_ID
)
INTO TABLE TF_RTB9_DTL 
WHEN POA_COU_VAL = '0'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY "~" OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' 
TRAILING NULLCOLS 
( 
TRANS_TYP POSITION(3),
...      
...      
MAST_POA_ID "NULL"
)
```

Or consider using the `NULLIF` function ( http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/ldr_field_list.htm#i1009345 )

```
...
MAST_POA_ID NULLIF POA_COU_VAL = '0'
...
```

SQL*Loader is a a tricky tool, you'd most probably get quicker results with external tables, if you are able to use them (file has to be on the Oracle Server machine whereas SQL*Loader is able connect to any Oracle instance).